# Do we lose flexibility of Before trigger by shifting to Process Builder?

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, before-trigger

At TrailheadX the `Process Builder` session was a hit!

The recommended best practice was to choose `Process Builder` wherever possible.

But, I feel that before triggers are the way to put most of the thing especially, where the fields on same record are updated. This saves `SOQL`, `DML` in a transaction.

By choosing `Process Builder`, logic gets executed after the after triggers.

How can we best (if at all) use before triggers, if the field I need to use in before trigger is updated in `Process Builder` and before triggers never get executed after `Process Builder` is run?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the trigger would run again if the field was updated in a Process Builder Update Action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you care about order of execution, triggers are far from obsolete, and this consideration still offers a compelling argument for why you would choose an `Apex Trigger` over `Process Builder`. If you need to do data transformations before a `Validation Rule`, or before you execute cross-object logic, you should certainly still use an `Apex Trigger`.

The thing is, in simple transactions, this order of execution often does not matter. The key is that you should start with the assumption that the declarative tool is the right one, then look at reasons why you might need to go the more customized route. As developers, we should try to write as little code as possible. In general it incurs less technical debt.

**Edit**

One additional concern that may steer you away from `Process Builder` and towards using an `Apex Trigger` is performance. I don't think the former will ever truly rival the latter and for large volume transactions, using an `Apex Trigger` is probably the way to go.

Comment: I've converted my trigger to process builder hoping that it would be easy to maintain in the long run for admins. But got hit with cpu limits and Soql limits        . Are process builders good for bulk updates?

Comment: @Anusha Performance is, unfortunately, still another argument for trigger over pb. It is getting better each release, and they've come a long way, but it will never perform quite as well as a trigger. If bulk updates/data volume are a concern, triggers are still a great option. I'll update my answer to reflect this additional concern.

Comment: Yeah, For the way process builders perform as of today, triggers seem the best option.